# A word to describe being the only one privy to the truth

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine that you are in a situation where you can tell that someone is putting on an act in a desperate attempt to win everyone's sympathy, but only you can see through the act.  You observe your gullible associates with total incredulity.  What do you call this kind of situation where the truth of this melodrama is only clear to one person?

I don't know if such a term exists, but I assume it does.

Comment: I feel like this _all_ the time.

Comment: Not an answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassandra, TL;DR she would prophesy the future, no one would believe here, it would come true, nobody said 'gosh we should listen to her next time'

Comment: Is the presenter aware that their presentation is fake, or have they convinced themselves that it isn't? In that scenario, are you the only sane person among madmen? Are you surrounded completely by idiots, or is the presenter a cynic?

Comment: Gratuitous downvoting is a sign of moral decay.

Comment: One word? "Politics". :-) (In this case, though, it's the speaker who's the one person that know what's being said is complete and utter fakery.)

Comment: A cat at a doggy butt sniffing party would feel this way. Sadly, I don't think there's a single word to describe said feline.

Comment: There's a lot of terms like *esoteric* and *initiate* related to mystery religions or secret societies. For a more modern allegory, there's *red pill* or *red piller* (from The Matrix) but that can have some unsavory associations.

Comment: It's also related to [in the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_land_of_the_blind,_the_one-eyed_man_is_king), and movies like They Live and The Matrix.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you may just be a [***cynic***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynic), and the act isn't fake at all.

It is also possible that everyone else is just as aware of the fakery as you, but they are playing along and concealing this fact, in which case you might say that [***"the emperor has no clothes"***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes).

If you truly are the only person in the audience to see through the charade, then one might say that you are [***singularly***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/singular) [***perceptive***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perceptive) or [***uniquely***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unique) [***observant***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/observant).  Alternatively, one might say that you're [***cynically***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cynic) [***unsympathetic***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/unsympathetic), presumably on account of having seen this act before.  You might say that the melodramatist in your story has [***cried wolf***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Cried_Wolf) too many times.

Comment: Great reference to the monarch in the buff. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly one word, but Plato's Allegory of the Cave has a lot of the elements you are looking for -- the essential blindness of all but one, and that one sees outside the cave but it hurts him and he cannot convince the others to turn and look.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave

Comment: Made me think of Ulysses /Odysseus on Circe's Island. But I suppose he and Circe both saw the truth.

Comment: If our proverbial BS speaker, in the back of their mind, was consciously using their power of oration to achieve the effect (as opposed to being genuine and honest), then yes, that (Circe) is quite the appropriate comparison.

Answer (score 0):

**Disaffected** might be made to work here, especially in the older sense of the term:

[Websters 1828](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=disaffected&quicksearch=on&sourceid=Mozilla-search):

> DISAFFECTED, pp. or a. Having the affections alienated; indisposed to favor or support; unfriendly; followed by with or to; as, these men are disaffected with the government, or disaffected to the king, or to the administration.

Hardly the perfect answer, but with the right set up it could get across what you're looking for.

"*Am I the sole disaffected one amongst this mob of credulous fools?*"

Answer (score 0):

I will go with ***clear-sighted***/***clear-sightedness***.

> clear-sighted: *fig.* seeing the truth [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/clear-sighted)
>
> clear-sightedness: the property of being clearsighted [Wiktionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/clear-sightedness)